# Arrow Function of JavaScript question - Multiple Arrow Function nesting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, cumulative-sum

I saw a answer  when I am practicing JS on leetcode, but I can't understand what this mean. can anyone expand the code? or tell me how to read this.

https://leetcode.com/problems/running-sum-of-1d-array/discuss/702025/one-liner

```js
let runningSum = nums => nums.map((sum => el => sum += el)(0));
console.log(runningSum([1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: This creates a function which maps over its parameter using a function (created by another function call) which adds up all elements, the `.map` is basically another way to `.reduce` (albeit more convoluted)

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding it, replace all the `x => y` parts with `function(x) { return y }`, starting at the inner-most level and working outwards

Comment: Or, in other words: an "immediately invoced function expression" (IIFE) provides the scope for creating the a summation function `el=>sum+=el` acting on the "private property" `sum` which is initialized through the argument `0` in its invocation.

Comment: As @Elias Schablowski said, it is another way of doing a `.reduce()` operation. Although I think the chosen approach is more elegant than the "reduce" way, which would be something like: `let runningSum=nums=>nums.reduce((a,c,i)=>(a.push(c+(i?a[i-1]:0)),a),[]);`.

Comment: @cars10m Wow , that was interesting, I will learn more about reduce.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original function

```
let runningSum = nums => nums.map((sum => el => sum += el)(0));
```

`(sum => el => sum += el)` is

```
function f1(sum) {
  return function f2(el) {
    return sum += el;
  }
}
```

(or in arrow format as shown by @Alterlife)

The original function then transforms into

```
let runningSum = nums => nums.map(f1(0));
```

then `nums.map(f1(0));`

becomes

```
const result = [];
const f2 = f1(0);

for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
  const num = nums[i];
  result.push(f2(num));
}
```

So all together, the original function transforms into

```
const nums = [1,2,3,4];
function f1(sum) {
  return function f2(el) {
    return sum += el;
  }
}
const result = [];
const f2 = f1(0);

for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
  const num = nums[i];
  result.push(f2(num));
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like this is a kind of compiler sugar?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try and break it down.

`(sum => el => sum += el)` , is equivalent to:

```
const mySumFunction = (sum) => {

   const addToSum = (el) => { 
      sum += el;
      return sum;
   }

   return addToSum;
}
```

This is a function that takes in a parameter - a starting sum. The sum parameter is also local variable within the function's scope.

When you call mySumFunction, it returns another function that adds to the local scoped variable sum and returns the total sum so far.

In effect, it creates a "function with memory" that returns the sum of everything that has been passed into it so far.

You can test this out as follows:

```
cumilativeSum = mySumFunction(0)
console.log(v(1)) // returns 1
console.log(v(1)) // returns 2
console.log(v(4)) // returns 6
```

Now let's look at the code as a whole.

```
let runningSum = nums => nums.map((sum => el => sum += el)(0));
```

The entire snippet passed into the map function: `(sum => el => sum += el)(0)` creates a "sum function with memory" that starts at 0, as we figured out above.

We're passing each of the numbers in an array to it and creating an array with the cumulative sum.

Comment: Thank you very much, the concept of "function with memory" really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take `(sum => el => sum += el)(0)` this self invocation arrow function for 1st iteration of map. Up on execution it return another arrow function `el => sum += el`. The value of sum is `0` which is passed as argument. Now keep come to our map 1st iteration

```
let runningSum = nums => nums.map(el => sum = 0 + el);
```

It returns 1. So, for the 2nd iteration, the value of the sum is 1 and el is 2.
so it returns 3, then 6 and then 10.

```
let runningSum = (nums) =>
  nums.map(
   (function (sum) {
         return (el) => (sum += el);
   })(0)
  );
console.log(runningSum([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```